# Get list of timezones from date.fns library

Tags: react-native, date-fns

Is it possible to get a list of all timezones from date.fns.
I decided to go with date.fns over moment cos moment is deprecated but moment has moment-timezone and with moment.tz.names() to get the list.

Is there an active equivalent for date.fns. Or another library that I could use in react native.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately date-fns doesn't have a timezone list, but you can use something like https://github.com/omsrivastava/timezones-list to get the list of timezones which is similar to `moment.tz.names()`